# How to copy all contents in a folder to a dir in php

Tags: php, file, copy

I am trying to copy all the files from a directory to another directory in php.

```
 $copy_all_files_from = "layouts/";
 $copy_to = "Website3/";
```

Can someone help me do this please.

Comment: I am getting the the following error

Warning: copy() [function.copy]: The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in

Comment: Sorry I found it now

http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-copy-file-or-directory-in-php-scripts-code-copying-files-directories-t5847.html

Answer (score 5):

Something like this(untested):

```
<?php
$handle = opendir($copy_all_files_from);
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    copy( $file, $copy_to);
    }
```

### edit:

To use Amadan's method, you should be able to use this php function:
shell_exec();

Not sure since I never need to use server commands

Comment: Definitely better than my reimplementing `copy` :) NB: Doesn't work for subdirectories.

Comment: I gave him a starting point, figuring out the subdirectories will be a good way to learn for him :)

Comment: To use @Amadan's method, you just need to type it like it is :) From the docs for shell_exec: "This function is identical to the backtick operator." Shell commands are useful since they are the most efficient at what they do, and tested for decades. Any reimplementation of, say recursive copy has an extremely low chance of beating `cp -r`.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest:

```
`cp -r $copy_all_files_from $copy_to`
```

Unless you're on Windows. Without shelling, it's a bit more complex: [read directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), [iterate on files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) (if [it's a directory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php), recurse), [open each](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), iterate while not [end of file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php), [read block](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and [write it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

**UPDATE:** doh, PHP has `copy`...

Comment: I know. But it's still easiest, and sufficient for most purposes. And backticks are proper PHP. I did add what he needs to know in order to implement in pure PHP if he needs it.

Comment: You don't have to open each file to read it and then write it, you can use copy(), see my comment ...

Comment: Ah, you added it, I thought i had misread and deleted my comment, sorry